# Оценка скрипта регистрации

Tags: php, инспекция-кода, регистрация

```
//Имя базы
$table = 'users';

//Коннектимся в базе
mysql_connect("localhost", "root") or die("Error connect to server");
mysql_select_db("aaa") or die("Error select db");

//Выводим все ошибки
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//Массив ошибок
$error = array();
if (isset($_POST['ok'])) {

    //Инициализируем переменные
    $login = !empty($_POST['login']) ? trim($_POST['login']) : NULL;
    $pass  = !empty($_POST['pass']) ? trim($_POST['pass']) : NULL;

    //Проверяем, занят ли логин, введенный юзверем
    $sql   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " . $table . "
            WHERE `login` =  '" . mysql_real_escape_string($login) . "'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
        $error[] = '<p>Этот логин занят, выберите другой</p>';

    //Проверяем поля на заполненность
    if ($login == '' or $pass == '')
        $error[] = '<p>Заполните все поля</p>';
    if (count($error) == 0) {
        $sql2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO " . $table . " (`login`, `pass`)
                               VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($login) . "', '" . md5($pass) . "')");
        if ($sql2 === TRUE)
            echo '<p>Вы успешно зарегистрированы!</p>';
    } else

    //Выводим ошибки, если они есть
        foreach ($error as $error_val)
            echo $error_val . '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$table."
    WHERE `login` =  '".mysql_real_escape_string($login)."'");
```

Ну если ты только логин проверяешь, то зачем ***** напиши просто

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT login FROM ".$table."
    WHERE `login` =  '".mysql_real_escape_string($login)."'");
```

- ко всему, ну регистрация понятна, а если пользователь забыл пароль как ему восстановить его? где вставка **email** хотя бы?

Ну как-то так.

Comment: эт я ща просто так накатал)) она из 100 тока на 5 процентов ведь сделала))))

Answer (score 1):

Я бы поменял местами блоки проверки заполнения полей (сначала надо ее сделать) и проверка, занят ли ник. И в проверке заполнения поставил бы по три равенства, а не по два (проверка все-таки идет на пустое место, а не на числовой ноль).
Причем логин сразу надо в переменной переводить в `mysql_real_escape_string()`.
Перед этим правда отсекать символы, которых не должно быть (запрещенные), а так в целом все более или менее нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Из грубых ошибок:

1. `error_reporting(E_ALL);` - Должен быть на самом верху
2. `if ($login == '' or $pass == '')` - Должен быть до того как мы начали что-либо делать с базой
3. `if (mysql_num_rows ($sql) > 0)` заменить на `if ($sql !== FALSE and mysql_num_rows ($sql) > 0)` или даже проверку `$sql !== FALSE` делать отдельно, так как может случится так что SELECT вернул ошибку

Из того что можно улучшить:

1. Не делать каждый раз: `mysql_real_escape_string($login)`, а сделать это один раз
2. `if (isset ($_POST['ok']))`
   заменить на `if( isset($_SERVER,$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' )`

Comment: Спасибо! Учту!

Answer (score 0):

Одно из правил, после отправки данных,например, POST-ом, делать редирект на страницу с выводом результата операции. В противном случае, при повторном нажатии F5, вылезет шокирующее окошко о повтороной отправке данных.